# Incorporating Known Limits into Time-Series Forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, forecast

I am trying to forecast a time-series with clear seasonality. I believe there is weekly and daily seasonality, and have a time-series sampled at 1-minute intervals over a year. To start, I fit a dynamic harmonic regression model with ARMA errors, by doing:

```
library("forecast")
fourier_components <- fourier( x = data, K=c(k_value,k_value) )
arima_model_fit <- auto.arima( data, seasonal=FALSE, lambda=0, xreg=fourier_components )
```

And this, as a first attempt (I can tune K and so on), works reasonably well. If I forecast ahead, I get:

```
forecast_fourier <- fourier( x = data, K=c(k_value, k_value), h = 1440*7*4 )
seasonal_test_forecast <- forecast( object = arima_model_fit, xreg = forecast_fourier )
autoplot(seasonal_test_forecast, include = 1440*7*4*2, ylab="data")
```

[image: Example Forecast]

However, I know due to physical limitations that the time-series cannot go below 0 or above some threshold T. I can stop the prediction intervals going below 0 with the lambda=0 call in auto.arima, as this provides a log-transform. But, is there some way I can account for the upper limit in the typical behaviour? Without explicitly doing it, I clearly get physically unreasonable prediction intervals over longer horizons.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, a method to account for this is detailed in otexts.com/fpp2/limits.html using an adjustment to the log-transform.

Comment: See https://otexts.com/fpp2/limits.html

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.